# how to setup codeigniter 3 cronjob in 20i server

Tags: php, cron, codeigniter-3, kubernetes-cronjob

I want to call the

url: http://page-finejewellery-co-uk.stackstaging.com/decorus/files

I have tried but not working

```
/usr/bin/php73 -q /home/sites/13a/1/1ff02ce814/www.page-finejewellery-co-uk.stackstaging.com/decorus/files >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Also tried

```
/usr/bin/php73 -q /home/sites/13a/1/1ff02ce814/public_html/index.php todecorus/ToDecorus index >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I want to call the `controller` `application/controllers/decorus/ToDecorus/index` my route is `decorus/files`

Comment: Consider editing your question to describe how what you have tried is not working.

Answer (score 0):

i have find it
/usr/bin/php73 -q /home/sites/13a/1/1ff02ce814/public_html/index.php towebsite/ToWebsite index >/dev/null 2>&1

towebsite/ToWebsite folder and controller